# chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow change event

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

The Google Chrome extension API provides info on the currently open window, using chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow, but it doesn't provide events for when it changes. I may refresh or redirect the page and I'd like the DevTools panel I'm adding to be notified. Is there a method for this?

Think of the Elements panel, it always stays up to date with the current DOM. This might be hard to implement in order to stay up to date like it does, whenever a DOM mutation happens, but I'd like at least to be notified when a new page is loaded (probably on the document.onload event, why not)

Any ideas on how to implement this, thanks?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Listen to one of the [`chrome.webNavigation`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation) events, and [notify](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) the devtools whenever an update occurs.

Another way to detect that the inspected page is being unloaded is to use the [`chrome.devtools.network.onNavigated`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools.network#event-onNavigated) event (only available within your devtools extension page).

Comment: OK, thanks for giving me a lead, here's a more narrow explanation of what I want to build, maybe you can point me some more to the right API methods, because the messaging between background, pages and devtools scripts can be tricky. I want to show some stats based on some global variables from pages that use a certain JS framework. So I would need to access the runtime JS variables of the currently opened page inside my devtools page. Is this possible? Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's possible. I suggest to add a button so that the user can manually trigger your code (that checks the global variables). The APIs I've linked are sufficient to get you started. Let me know when you get stuck.

Comment: OK, I managed to bind chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted handlers to independent devtools panels through the background script. So far so good, but how do I get from the basic `details` params from https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation.html#event-onCompleted to access that tab's global variables? Thanks

Comment: @treznik You can't directly access the global variables. Just send a message to the devtools panel that the page has been refeshed and that the global variables should be looked up again.

Comment: Where would they be looked up, then? Can I access them from the devtools panel or do I need to add content_scripts in the mix as well?

Comment: @treznik They can directly be read using [`chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools.inspectedWindow.html#method-eval). If you prefer to get the information in the background page, [`chrome.tabs.executeScript`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript) can also be used.

Comment: chrome.devtools.network.onNavigated and onRequestFinished was exactly  what I wanted.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same challenge, and this was the only result I found in Google, so I wanted to answer with the solution I found. The key lies not in `chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow`, but in `chrome.tabs.onUpdated`. In fact, I've found `chrome.tabs.*` to be much more useful in general. Here's the code I'm using to watch state changes from my extension;

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changes, tabObject) {
  console.log("Status of", tabId, "is", changes.status);
  if (changes.status == "complete") {
    console.log("Tab Load Complete");
  }
});
```

You could also use the `chrome.tabs.*` API to check whether the status change happened on the current tab or not.

Comment: You cannot use chrome.tabs code in the devtools page, which is where the OP is asking for.

I'm not going to downvote you, since it seems some people obviously found your solution useful, but I doubt they were trying to make a Devtools panel.